# Posting and fetching url parameters inside a jsp in struts

Tags: jsp, struts

I am trying to get the parameters of an url in a .jsp using struts lib and create a custom url for the action attribute of a form inside the jsp page using that parameter.

JavaScript where parameter is populated:

```
function openNewWindow(qtype) {
    var x = screen.width / 3;
    var y = screen.height / 3;

    window.open('FileUpload.jsp?q=' + qtype, 'UploadExelSheet',
            'height=250,width=400');

}
```

After redirection to FileUpload.jsp from the javascript,
Sample url of the jsp page:
http://localhost:8080/QuizApp/FileUpload.jsp?q=1

Here is what I have tried to fetch the 'q' value inside FileUpload.jsp and create the custom url for an action form:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh"
    content="${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval}; url=Timedout.jsp?type=timeout; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<script src="js/myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>File Upload:</h3>
    Select a file to upload:
    <br />
    <c:set var="qtype" value="uploadq?q=${q}" />
    <s:url action="%{qtype}" var="myUrl"/>

    <s:form action="%{#myUrl}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="upload" id="uploadfile" size="50" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" />
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your q paramete in jsp like this:

```
${param.q}
```

So in your FileUpload.jsp you can use Struts2 tags to set values(s:set insteaof c:set)  the following code:

```
<s:set var="qtype" value="uploadq?q=${param.q}" />
```

Or you can construct the URL with the following code:

```
<s:url id="myUrl" action="uploadq" var="myUrl">
    <s:param name="q">${param.q}</s:param>
</s:url>
```

For your Form you can use qtype or myUrlvar for action attribute  using OGNL like below:

```
<s:form action="%{#qtype}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="upload" id="uploadfile" size="50" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</s:form>
```

Or

```
<s:form action="%{#myUrl}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="upload" id="uploadfile" size="50" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</s:form>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The value is getting fetched in the page, but the dynamic url in action is showing blank
<form id="" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> during actual runtime
while using <s:form action="%{#qtype}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: You have # on your value, remove it.

Comment: Tried removing the #,still not working :(
<s:form action="%{qtype}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Can you try action="%{#myUrl}", modify your s:url tag like on the answer.

Comment: Or you can use struts taggs s:set instead of c:set and then use OGNL to put action attribute action="%{#qtype}"